# How to embed a Java applet in a web page?

Tags: java, applet

I am using the following code to embed a Java applet in a web page,

```
<APPLET CODE="main.class" WIDTH=500 HEIGHT=80 archive='testing.jar'>
</APPLET>
```

But the problem is, the class file for my applet is in a package named `environment`, 
which means my `main.class` is inside a folder environment.

The browser show me the error message that it can't search my class file when I use

```
CODE="main.class"
```

How can I set it to refer the class file in a package in the jar file which I export out?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'll probably want to take a look at [Deploying an Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/runAppletFunction.html) and [Deploying With the Applet Tag](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html). Here's a small [working example](http://whitefang34.com/ImageIconApplet.html) of an applet that might help you. The HTML for that page is simply:

```
<applet width="200" height="200" archive="ImageIconApplet.jar"
        code="com.whitefang34.ImageIconApplet" />
```

The applet source code is:

```
package com.whitefang34;

public class ImageIconApplet extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/images/WhiteFang34.jpg");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(url);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon, JLabel.CENTER);
        add(label);
    }
}
```

And the [packaged jar](http://whitefang34.com/ImageIconApplet.jar) for the applet contains:

```
/com/whitefang34/ImageIconApplet.class
/images/WhiteFang34.jpg
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that the `<applet>` tag is obsolete in HTML5, use `<object>` instead.