# How to post a simple Java mathematical calculation app on a cpanel linux hosted wordpress website?

Tags: java, linux, wordpress

I have just started learning Java programming **(Yes, I am an absolute beginner and use Java only in the training institute)** and I want to post a simple Java calculation app on a cPanel Linux hosted WordPress website. How can I do this in simple steps?

Comment: I doubt Java isn't  an overkill for "simple mathematical calculation". If You still prefer Java - embedding Java applet into WordPress should be trivial task, similar to the one described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5693088/1150918). As mentioned in the linked answer, You should check out these official resources about Java applets and their deployment, like [docs.oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/).

Answer (score 1):

```
<applet code="SomeApplet.class" width=480 height=240 codebase="http://www.yoururl.com/wp-content/applet";>
<param name="iconwidth" value="48">
</param><param name="iconheight" value="48">
</param></applet>
```

This could work.

Or maybe preferably this:

```
<applet width="400" height="400" archive="/applets/interleaves.jar" code="interleaves" />
```

If you use Eclipse (or any other IDE) it's fairly simple creating a .class file to a .jar.

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and for sharing your knowledge. I was trying to put up an EMI calculator on a website. I think this should help.

Comment: Concider marking this as an answer or vote up the comment if it fits you.